# Duplication of data entries by id if they meet a certain condition

Tags: stata

In the original choice data set, individuals (`id`) are captured making purchases (`choice`) among all the product options possible (`assortchoice` is a product code). Every individual always faces the same set of products to choose from; as a result the value of `choice` is always either 0 or 1 ("was the product chosen or not?").

```
clear
input
id  assortchoice    choice  sumchoice
2   12  1   2
2   13  0   2
2   14  0   2
2   15  0   2
2   16  0   2
2   17  0   2
2   18  0   2
2   19  0   2
2   20  0   2
2   21  0   2
2   22  0   2
2   23  1   2

3   12  1   1
3   13  0   1
3   14  0   1
3   15  0   1
3   16  0   1
3   17  0   1
3   18  0   1
3   19  0   1
3   20  0   1
3   21  0   1
3   22  0   1
3   23  0   1

4   12  1   3
4   13  0   3
4   14  1   3
4   15  1   3
4   16  0   3
4   17  0   3
4   18  0   3
4   19  0   3
4   20  0   3
4   21  0   3
4   22  0   3
4   23  0   3
end
```

I created the following code to understand how many choices were made by each individual:

```
egen sumchoice=total(choice), by(id)
```

In this example, an individual 3 (id=3) only chose one product (since sumchoice=1), but individual 2 made two choices (sumchoice=2). Finally, individual 4 made three choices (sumchoice=3).

Since this is a choice data, **I need to transform all the instances of multiple choices into sets of single  choices**.

What I mean by that: if an individual made two purchases, I need to duplicate the choice set for that individual twice; for an individual who made 3 purchases, I need to replicate the choice set three times, so the final structure looks like the data set below.

```
clear
input
id  transaction assortchoice    choice
2   1   12  1
2   1   13  0
2   1   14  0
2   1   15  0
2   1   16  0
2   1   17  0
2   1   18  0
2   1   19  0
2   1   20  0
2   1   21  0
2   1   22  0
2   1   23  0

2   2   12  0
2   2   13  0
2   2   14  0
2   2   15  0
2   2   16  0
2   2   17  0
2   2   18  0
2   2   19  0
2   2   20  0
2   2   21  0
2   2   22  0
2   2   23  1
            
3   1   12  1
3   1   13  0
3   1   14  0
3   1   15  0
3   1   16  0
3   1   17  0
3   1   18  0
3   1   19  0
3   1   20  0
3   1   21  0
3   1   22  0
3   1   23  0
            
4   1   12  1
4   1   13  0
4   1   14  0
4   1   15  0
4   1   16  0
4   1   17  0
4   1   18  0
4   1   19  0
4   1   20  0
4   1   21  0
4   1   22  0
4   1   23  0
            
4   2   12  0
4   2   13  0
4   2   14  1
4   2   15  0
4   2   16  0
4   2   17  0
4   2   18  0
4   2   19  0
4   2   20  0
4   2   21  0
4   2   22  0
4   2   23  0
            
4   3   12  0
4   3   13  0
4   3   14  0
4   3   15  1
4   3   16  0
4   3   17  0
4   3   18  0
4   3   19  0
4   3   20  0
4   3   21  0
4   3   22  0
4   3   23  0

end
```

***update:

`transaction` indicates which transaction order this is:

```
bysort id assortchoice (choice): gen transaction=_n
```

Hence, choice=1 should appear only **once** per each transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The answer isn't quite "use `expand`" as there is a twist that you don't want exact replicates.

```
expand sumchoice 
bysort id assortchoice (choice) : replace choice = 0 if _n != _N & choice == 1 
list if id == 2 , sepby(assortchoice)

     +-----------------------------------+
     | id   assort~e   choice   sumcho~e |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |  2         12        0          2 |
  2. |  2         12        1          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  3. |  2         13        0          2 |
  4. |  2         13        0          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  5. |  2         14        0          2 |
  6. |  2         14        0          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  7. |  2         15        0          2 |
  8. |  2         15        0          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  9. |  2         16        0          2 |
 10. |  2         16        0          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 11. |  2         17        0          2 |
 12. |  2         17        0          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 13. |  2         18        0          2 |
 14. |  2         18        0          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 15. |  2         19        0          2 |
 16. |  2         19        0          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 17. |  2         20        0          2 |
 18. |  2         20        0          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 19. |  2         21        0          2 |
 20. |  2         21        0          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 21. |  2         22        0          2 |
 22. |  2         22        0          2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 23. |  2         23        0          2 |
 24. |  2         23        1          2 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well. Is it possible to create a variable as "transaction" too which indicates a transaction order? (I cannot run a regression without that piece of information.)

Comment: What in your data gives that information?

Comment: I would say `sumchoice` (the one that I generated to see how many transactions were made by a person)

Comment: It doesn't have to be the order. It just has to be an indicator of transaction number.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. You already have `sumchoice`. `choice == 1` indicates your choices. But `choice == 1` is exactly the same as `choice`.

Comment: In the post, I have the final data set that I would like to have - the second variable is `transaction`. It makes a distinction among all the additionally created entries (first purchase (transaction=1), second purchase (transaction=2), third purchase (transaction=3).

Comment: Indeed, but I do not understand where `transaction` comes from.

Comment: `transaction` takes information from `sumchoice` if you will. `sumchoice` signals that there must be done _N number of replications. Transaction then lists all those replications (1, 2, 3...) referring to the total number of those transactions in `sumchoice`.

Comment: I trust that someone else can follow this. I can't help further.

Comment: Thank you Nick for your help. I hope someone can help me with that - otherwise, my dataset cannot be declared as panel.

Comment: That's incorrect. You don't need a time variable to declare a panel dataset, just an identifier.

Comment: I am trying to recreate the sample data set provided in this Stata manual on p. 97: www.stata.com/manuals/cm.pdf. In this example, consumerid=6 only has 1 car, whereas consumerid=7 has two cars. They have a separate variable `carnumber` to indicate that. I have tried without that piece of information, but I am unable to declare the data set panel using `cmset` (p.98 of the manual). If I am not getting the manual example right, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: I wonder if someone can help me recreate the stata data example on p. 94 of www.stata.com/manuals/cm.pdf. Without the transaction identifier, I am not able to declare the data as panel and run a regression. That's because the transactions happened at the same time for the same household, and stata sees it as duplication.

Comment: I have been able to create a new variable that generates the transaction order. Is it possible to use that information to do what you did in this thread using `expand` with a twist? Please see the updated code.